# Is there a way to make Jenkins display test results graphically in a job column?

Tags: jenkins

I've spent a while trying to get my Jenkins view to show the information I want about my test jobs, however I can't find a way to concisely display test results graphically. I am currently using Dashboard View image portlets to link to the graphs generated at `job/<job-name>/test/trend`, however this is still quite limited. I also have [Test Results Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin) which generates some nice graphs, but this required navigating to a separate page for each job. What I would like is the ability to include the horizontal bar from the Test Results Analyzer 'build status' chart for the latest build as a column in the jobs table, something like this:
[image: job table idea]
Does anyone know if there is any tool or plugin to produce something like that?

Comment: If the existing answer helps, please vote it up. If it gave you what you needed to solve the question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has an [API](https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with which you can make your own [radiator dashboard view](https://www.google.nl/search?q=radiator%20%20jenkins%20dashboard&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9ubSyyJPNAhXG2RoKHWCrDl0Q_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=955). I don't think you can build what you want with the standard plugins.

Some developers already created external views with the API. Maybe something like [this](http://qone.io/jenkins/react/dashboard/testing/stats/2015/11/14/jenkins-test-dashboard.html) is what you are looking for. Should be relative easy for a developer to extend.

[image]

Here is another one which looks promising: https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/01/10/beautiful-jenkins-dashboard/